# How to speed up drawing plots in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, random, plot, random-walk

I'm playing with random walk, I have two points. First one is walking randomly, second one is trying to escape from his area, which is given by formula e^(-t), where t is the distance between the two points. In my opinion it is not a difficult program, but it takes about a minute to run it with hundred points to calculate, so I'm asking you to help me find some way to speed it up and explain it to me.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x, y, zx, zy):
    return np.exp(-np.sqrt((x-zx)**2+(y-zy)**2))


x = y = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 6))
#random picking first location for two points
loksx = [np.random.randn(), ]
loksy = [np.random.randn(), ]
lokzx = [np.random.randn(), ]
lokzy = [np.random.randn(), ]
for i in range(100):
    lokzx.append(np.random.randn()+lokzx[-1])
    lokzy.append(np.random.randn()+lokzy[-1])
    nsx = np.random.randn()
    nsy = np.random.randn()
    #checking if the next step has smaller value than the last one 
    if f(loksx[-1]+nsx, loksy[-1]+nsy, lokzx[-1], lokzy[-1]) < f(loksx[-1], loksy[-1], lokzx[-1], lokzy[-1]):
        loksx.append(nsx+loksx[-1])
        loksy.append(nsy+loksy[-1])
Z = []
for i in range(len(lokzx)):
    Z.append(f(X, Y, lokzx[i], lokzy[i]))
ax.plot(lokzx[0], lokzy[0], 'y,',markersize=1)
ax.plot(loksx[0], loksy[0], 'w,', markersize=1)
ax.plot(lokzx[1:-1], lokzy[1:-1], 'g,',markersize=1)
ax.plot(loksx[1:-1], loksy[1:-1], 'b,', markersize=1)

ax.plot(loksx[-1], loksy[-1], 'k,', markersize=1)
ax.plot(lokzx[-1], lokzy[-1], 'r,',markersize=1)
for i in range(len(Z)):
    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z[i], 20, cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.01)
ax.plot()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

@edit 
Now instead of using lists I'm using nparrays:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x, y, zx, zy):
    return np.exp(-np.sqrt((x-zx)**2+(y-zy)**2))


x = y = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 6))
lokzx = np.random.randn(100)
lokzy = np.random.randn(100)
loksx = np.zeros(100)
loksy = np.zeros(100)
for i in range(1,100):
    nsx = np.random.randn()
    nsy = np.random.randn()
    if f(loksx[i-1]+nsx, loksy[i-1]+nsy, lokzx[i-1], lokzy[i-1]) < f(loksx[i-1], loksy[i-1], lokzx[i-1], lokzy[i-1]):
        loksx[i] = loksx[i-1]+nsx
        loksy[i] = loksy[i-1]+nsy
    else:
        loksx[i] = loksx[i-1]
        loksy[i] = loksy[i-1]
Z = np.zeros((100,1000,1000))
for i in range(len(lokzx)):
    Z[i] = f(X, Y, lokzx[i], lokzy[i])

ax.plot(lokzx[0], lokzy[0], 'y,',markersize=1)
ax.plot(loksx[0], loksy[0], 'w,', markersize=1)
ax.plot(lokzx[1:-1], lokzy[1:-1], 'g,',markersize=1)
ax.plot(loksx[1:-1], loksy[1:-1], 'b,', markersize=1)

ax.plot(loksx[-1], loksy[-1], 'k,', markersize=1)
ax.plot(lokzx[-1], lokzy[-1], 'r,',markersize=1)
for i in range(len(Z)):
    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z[i], 20, cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.01)
ax.plot()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

But still it takes a while to run this. The only problem left is this two lines of code:

```py
for i in range(len(Z)):
    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z[i], 20, cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.01)
```

But I don't know how to rewrite this without using a loop.

Comment: It's probably not the plotting that's slow. It's most likely the loops.

Comment: there's a good documentation here: https://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html

Comment: Ok well you are calling contour 1000 times.  That will definitely be slow. It’s unclear why you are calling contour 1000 times.

Comment: @JodyKlymak because I want to see what the area was in each point

Comment: Can you link an image to what you are trying to do?

Comment: @JodyKlymak here is what I'm trying to do: https://imgur.com/a/JXdnZB8

Comment: The image on Imagur is just a maroon color in an axes...

Comment: @JodyKlymak here you have more zoomed version: https://imgur.com/a/YTmj7vL

Comment: I don't know what you think you can see w/ that contour; its just a mess to me. Doing 1000 of them will definitely take some time.  Suggest you come up w/ a visualization that doesn't require so many contours.  Its not like its hard for a viewer to gauge the distance from a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to avoid the loops by learning to use the appropriate numpy functions.   i.e. something like the below will be much faster:

```
dx = np.random.randn(100)
dy = np.random.randn(100)
x = np.cumsum(dx)
y = np.cumsum(dy)
```

If you *really* need the for-loop, preallocate your array; don't keep appending:

```
x = np.zeros(100)
y = np.zeros(100)
for i in range(1, 100):
    x[i] = x[i-1] + np.random.randn()
    y[i] = y[i-1] + np.random.randn()
```

Comment: Despite the changes, it still needs a while to draw it. I think main problem is in this loop:
```python
 for i in range(len(Z)):
    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z[i], 20, cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.01)
```
but I don't know how I can write it different.